# Keep Track of Current Line Being Scanned

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am using a scanner to scan input from the command prompt, and I need to keep track of what line a particular word is on.  If I enter through the command prompt this input:

"First line

Now second line

Finally last line"

I want it to print out:

"Word: First line: 1

Word: line line: 1

Word: Now line: 2

Word: second line: 2

Word: line line: 2

Word Finally line: 3

Word last line: 3

Word line line: 3"

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lineNum = 1;
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        if(scan.next().matches("[\\n]")
            lineNum++;
        System.out.println("Word: " + scan.next() + " line: " + lineNum);
    }
}
```

I have tried many different regex patters, but none I have tried seem to do the trick.  I've tried some other methods to increment the counter such as increment for scan.hasNextLine, but no success and I feel there has to be a pretty simple way to do this I'm just not finding it.

Comment: Try reading in one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes. You can do it by reading each line while [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) and then splitting the words in the line with something like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int lineNum = 1;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.printf("Word: %s line: %d %n", word, lineNum);
    }
    lineNum++; // <-- then increment the line count.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to give up on using `Scanner` to do the word breaking!

Read in a whole line, then use `String.split(" ")` to break the line into words.

If you're dead keen on sticking with `Scanner` for all aspects, you can use one `Scanner` to read in the next line, and then use another `Scanner` to do the word breaking on what you just read in:

```
String wholeLine = scan.nextLine();
Scanner innerScan = new Scanner(wholeLine);
lineNum++;
while (innerScan.hasNext())
    System.out.println("Word: " + innerScan.next() + " line: " + lineNum);
```

That saves you worrying about regular expressions for the `String.split()`.